# When i dump data in my MySQL tables in my Ruby on rails application, why it displays special characters?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, special-characters

In my ruby on rails application,

When i dump data in to my data base from file like `(CSV, txt, XLS)` it display special character like `D�e�m�o` in my production database. But in my file the data is `"Demo"`. So why it happens. It looks like my real time data is corrupted.

I am using,

```
Ruby 1.9.2p180 
Rails 3.0.5 
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.13
Mysql
```

It still displays in my browser:

[image]

Why it happens?

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using an incorrect charset for your table (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-table.html)), connection (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)) or you aren't specifying one at all. Also, the file (CSV, TXT or XLS for example) could be in a specific encoding and be read (e.g. "interpreted") with another (incorrect) encoding.

Before you start changing stuff around, guessing the correct charset to use, you should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to save yourself a lot of headaches and frustration.

Comment: Thanks, i am using UTF-8 encoding in my application while dumping data in to database. I googled and found it happens due to UTF-16 encoding. But it's not worked for me still am having the same problem.

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to? You're saying you're using UTF-8 in your *application*. So what about the database? Is it in UTF-8 too? And the actual table? And did you set the correct charset on your connection? And how about the file(s)? Are they all UTF-8 as well? I've provided plenty of links in my answer and the one with the longest title ending in "No excuses" is in there with a reason (as well as the 'No excuses!' part in the title). Also, when you say *"But it's not worked for me"* you should at least specify *what* you changed.

Comment: Yes, i have checked links and it explained nicely +1 for your efforts. But in my application i am using same encoding in data base as well. My files are also in UTF-8 charset.

Comment: So your files are in UTF-8, your database (and table!) is in UTF-8, your connection is set to UTF-8 and Ruby uses UTF-16 as default (I'm assuming this from your comment(s), I'm not familiar with Ruby other than reading some blogposts about it sometimes). See where I'm [hinting at](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5908774/215042)? Either way, *somewhere* in the chain there's a different encoding so you'll need to start checking the entire chain, step-by-step. You'll find your problem for sure. Also, to be honest, I think you *"read"* that article pretty fast ;-) Are you sure you **understand** it?

Comment: I am checking it on my local system. By setting default encoding to UTF-8 as mentioned in link. As my production server has important data. So it will takes some time to check on live.

Comment: Also, did you try googling for an answer? I found one in a blink of the eye: [ruby mysql utf8](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+mysql+utf8): [here](https://my.a2hosting.com/knowledgebase.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=794). Seems you need to change `database.yml` as well (which makes sense I guess).

Comment: I have found my problem in the above mentioned link. Now i am implementing it. Lets see what happens. database.yml represents encoding UTF-8 in mycase.

Comment: Now again it happens, please see my update question screenshot of my browser

Comment: Sceenshots show nothing but the problem; what we need is *relevant* code / settings. This includes the charset used in your HTML output (e.g. `<meta charset="...">`), code where you set connection charsets (e.g. `db.options(Mysql::SET_CHARSET_NAME, 'utf8')`), alter/create-table scripts that define DB/table charsets, the aforementioned `database.yml` etc. As I've regurgitated about 15 times by now: **any one of those** (and more) can be the source of your problem. Your problem is (and was) perfectly clear, even without the screenshot.