# I receive "incompatible character encodings: CP850 and UTF-8" when displaying the £ symbol on my ramaze app

Tags: ruby, encoding, ramaze

I receive "incompatible character encodings: CP850 and UTF-8" when displaying the `£` symbol on my ramaze app. How can I get rid of this error? I have the UTF-8 meta tag in my head tag.

It happens when I type the `£` symbol with the keyboard. Look.

[image: encoding error]

I have put the following code in my ruby file and it hasn't fixed the problem.

```
# encoding: UTF-8 
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question?

Comment: So you already have this: `# encoding: UTF-8` on top of your ruby file?

Comment: To emulate the encoding problem on any system (or test the fix), you simply set the encoding to something other than UTF-8 when running Ruby:

`ruby -E US-ASCII my_script.rb`
Try this and let me know!

Comment: Check the encoding of your file using `file mytest.rb -i` command. If it is not `UTF-8` then change the file encoding to `UTF-8`

Comment: All my files are UTF-8

Comment: I changed the encoding of all my files to UTF-8 and I still get that error.

Comment: One time, it worked for me to delete the offending character and then copy it again from a different, utf8, source. It felt like this :P https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8

Comment: It happens when I type the `£` symbol with the keyboard. Look. http://i.imgur.com/eOGbsLT.gif

Comment: @desbest Please show your "Edit blog post" source code.

Comment: Here's the code for "edit blog post" @EugZol

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see it. Where is?

Comment: I forgot the link here it is. @EugZol https://gist.github.com/desbest/4bd9581dc6603ff0e9ee

Comment: @desbest To me, it looks like a client's issue, not server's. So you might be looking in the wrong place. Open your browser's console and provide screenshots of the request data please.

Comment: Here's a screenshot @EugZol http://imgur.com/1j8DdyF

Comment: @desbest please show `request headers` section as well. And `response headers` of your initial request (for the page on which there is form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to force the encoding to see if that makes the problem go away:

```
your_string.force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8)
```

If it does, dive into your app and spot what is setting the wrong encoding, where, and why.

It's possibly server-/webpage-related, as in the page you're serving is rendered as US-ASCII owing to a header. Or the server is started with encoding other than UTF-8. Or something other to that effect. Your script ends up with a piece of external data that isn't UTF-8.

Comment: Your line of code doesn't work. I tried this answer but it didn't work as I didn't have the `LC_ALL` variable defined on my computer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908774/set-global-default-encoding-for-ruby-1-9/17616076#17616076

Answer (score 1):

Windows issue? Try using Iconv:

`Iconv.conv('utf-8', "WINDOWS-1253", X)`

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the text from UTF-8 to another encoding and then back to UTF-8.

`content = content.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil)`

**Update:** This answer didn't work for me, but it might help you.