# How do I change ruby's default encoding to utf-8?

Tags: ruby

I ran `ruby -e 'p Encoding.default_external` and got this response.

`<Encoding:CP850>`

How do I change it to UTF-8?

Comment: what version of Ruby are you running? `UTF-8 is` the `default` encoding since Ruby 2.

Comment: (Really, this is fairly searchable on the web, although Google is pretty good at knowing what I mean.)

Comment: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521371/set-utf-8-as-default-for-ruby-1-9-3) to a question asked similar to yours, answered.

Comment: `ruby -h` will give you the answer.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.3. I searched google for `change ruby encoding` and didn't get any relevant results.

Comment: This seems to answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521371/set-utf-8-as-default-for-ruby-1-9-3

Comment: None of the links you have given me work. When I try to insert `£` into my database or display the `£` symbol in an xhtml file, I get an exception that a UTF-8 character cannot be displayed on a page with CP-850 encoding. This question will explain further. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909569/i-receive-incompatible-character-encodings-cp850-and-utf-8-when-displaying-th I have put `# encoding: UTF-8` `Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8';
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8` in my ruby file and it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: @desbest You said the magic word, "database". Your database will have its own encoding, usually per table.

Comment: The default I/O encoding is taken from your operating system's encoding settings. How to configure your operating system is a general user question, completely unrelated to programming, thus I vote to close as off-topic. (I would vote to migrate to SuperUser, except I'm betting this has already been asked there. Plus, the question doesn't have enough information, like what operating system the OP is using.)

Comment: This is not a database question @Schwern as I get an exception when I display a web page that has the `£` character on it. Also @Jörg I get the same error on Heroku, so it happens on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: This answer looks promising. How do I make it work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17616076/337306

Comment: I can't use this answer as I don't have the LC_ALL environment variable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17616076/337306